# Entity Framework 4 and Velocity

Tags: entity-framework, caching, appfabric

Did you ever used EF4 and Velocity(or other caching framework) together?

I found this blog post [Tracing and Caching EF](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html) distributed caching product. It's more mature than AppFabric (previously known as Velocity), and the latest version has support built in for Entity Framework.

Comment: It is good and it is expensive. Especially if EF is all you want.